# How do I merge Google calendars together?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

Within one Google apps account, I have 2 Google Calendars (called Program1 and Program2) with >100 events.

How do I merge the events from both calendars into a single calendar? Program 2 has now merged into Program 1, so their events no longer belong to one or the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can export Program 2 calendar and import its entries into the Program 1 calendar. Do this in Calendar > Calendar Settings where you'll find the export and import links near the "Create new calendar" button.